# Server-specific error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am running some scripts on identical databases on different servers.

While the script runs successfully on most of them, on some I am getting this error:

```
UPDATE DB.T1
SET SONUM = 0
WHERE SONUM <> 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT SERVICEORDER
        FROM DB.T2
        WHERE SERVICEORDER = T1.SONUM
        )
```

> The multi-part identifier `T1.SONUM` could not be bound

My question is, why it is running successfully on some servers but not all? and how can I fix it?

Can I replace the query above with this one?:

```
UPDATE DB.T1
SET SONUM = 0
WHERE SONUM NOT IN (
        SELECT SERVICEORDER
        FROM DB.T2
        )
    AND SONUM <> 0
```

Comment: You aren't showing us the right query.  I don't see `T1.SONUM` in either of those.

Comment: Thanks, Just edited

Comment: How do you have multiple "WHERE" clauses in your first statement?  You also don't show us where the "B5" table is coming from.  That statement wouldn't be able to run on any server.  The syntax has mistakes.

Comment: You have multiple `WHERE` statements in your first query, which should be throwing an error regardless of what client you run it on.  You also have a random `B5` table/alias that isn't mentioned anywhere else in the query.  Can you please show us the *actual* query you're using that's giving you this error?  The query you've provided would never run successfully on *any* client.

Comment: you mean my second query is fine , right?

Comment: Your second query has valid syntax.  Whether or not it is correct is not known.  We don't know your table structure, and I suspect the clients have different table structure between them if the query worked on some, but not on others.

Comment: no the second "where" was added here while I wanted to edit the query
..the first query execute successfully anywhere but not on that SQL 2008 R2, 

may I replace it with the second query, using "NOT IN" ?

Comment: clients' databases is our product database, all with the same structure

Comment: if the both queries do the same, I can use the second one I wrote?

Comment: You really should not be asking the internet for advice on how to update your client systems when you don't share the structure and intent of the update.  Yes, you can substitute the second query for the first one... *HOWEVER*... You already received an error message stating that the structure is *not* as you expected it to be.  It would be a better idea for you to look at the structure of the client database that the update failed on, and compose a `SELECT` statement to pull the intended records you want to update before blindly executing an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: forget about the update, lets say its a select, even when I select that condition it throw the same error for the first query,

do they select the same ? may I replace the first query which throw error with the second one?

select SONUM , * from  DB.T1
WHERE SONUM<>0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SERVICEORDER FROM DB.T2 WHERE SERVICEORDER = T1.SONUM)


select SONUM , * from  DB.T1
WHERE SONUM NOT IN (SELECT SERVICEORDER FROM DB.T2 ) AND SONUM<>''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your table an alias.  It seems like `T1` is in schema `DB`, the `EXISTS` is probably looking in the default `DBO`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE T
SET    SONUM = 0
FROM   DB.T1 T
WHERE  SONUM <> 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SERVICEORDER
                FROM   DB.T2
                WHERE  SERVICEORDER = T.SONUM)
```

Note: And of course, convert this to a select and make sure you are getting the correct results before updating.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you might be getting the error is because of inconsistencies between the column names between your tables. The column "SONUM" needs to exist in every table you're running this on.

After checking the table schema, if you decide you still want to make these updates.  The following query should do the same thing as you seem to want without a subquery.

It will Update the SONUM of DB.T1 to be 0 for each record that is not currently 0 and has no associated SERVICEORDER's from DB.T2.

First it would be a good idea to preview the columns you're going to update with a select statement.  The update statement to actually change them will follow.

```
SELECT DB.T1.SONUM
    , DB.T2.SERVICEORDER
FROM DB.T1
    LEFT JOIN DB.T2
        ON DB.T1.SONUM = DB.T2.SERVICEORDER
WHERE DB.T2.SERVICEORDER IS NULL
AND DB.T1.SONUM <> 0
```

And Update...

```
UPDATE DB.T1
SET SONUM = 0
FROM DB.T1
    LEFT JOIN DB.T2
        ON DB.T1.SONUM = DB.T2.SERVICEORDER
WHERE DB.T2.SERVICEORDER IS NULL
AND DB.T1.SONUM <> 0
```

Comment: UPDATE db.BIF050 SET D_DEPOSITQUOTEDDATE = 
(Select Case When D_DATERECEIVED< D_EXPIRYDATE AND D_DATERECEIVED<T_DATETIME Then D_DATERECEIVED
 When D_EXPIRYDATE<D_DATERECEIVED AND D_EXPIRYDATE<T_DATETIME Then D_EXPIRYDATE 
  Else  T_DATETIME End As D_DEPOSITQUOTEDDATE  
FROM db.BIF050 A WHERE A.I_PK = BIF050.I_PK) --
  WHERE D_DEPOSITQUOTEDDATE IS NULL
GO

Comment: same error..I am really confused by getting same error for all script someone else has written

Comment: is that related to the version of SQL?

Comment: What is this whole new query???  In this query you have a commented out where clause at the end and a "GO" batch seperator in the query.  Is this intentional?  Perhaps the error is caused by using the implicit join between your tables.  I would suggest using a join instead if possible but i'm also fairly certain that this type of implicit join has been supported for a long time.  Have you run my SELECT query above? did it give the same error?